# Javascript on form submit - success callback not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this Javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#please_wait_box").hide();
    $("#updateinvoice").submit(function(e){
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#please_wait_box").show();
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString=$("#updateinvoice").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "viewinvoices-popup_go.php",
            cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(res){
                $("#please_wait_box").hide();
                $("#message").html(res);
                $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
                $('.overlay').fadeOut();
                if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
                {
                    window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="message" class="messagebox"></div>
<div id="please_wait_box" class="messagebox">Please Wait...</div>
```

So on form submit it should display the `please_wait_box` div then the output in the `viewinvoices-popup_go.php` page should display in the `message` div.

But nothing is showing at all - the queries on the submit page are exciting fine though

Comment: Try to provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Eventually, did you try to show the DIV in the `beforeSend` function of `$.ajax()`? What if you remove the `$("#please_wait_box").hide();` is the DIV shown?

Comment: It doesn't seem to get triggered at all, try putting an alert inside the `submit` function. You may need to paste your form code too.

Answer (score -1):

You will need this :

```
   $("#updateinvoice").submit(function(e){   
     e.preventDefault();
     // You rst of the code
   });
```

Comment: @user007 is your success function getting called?

Comment: Lol, look again! I'm not the one who asked this question >,<

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try this it will work.

For hiding the message
$('#message').removeClass('messagebox');
$('#message').addClass('hidden');
$('#message').show();

For showing the please_wait_box.
$('#please_wait_box').removeClass('hidden');
$('#please_wait_box').addClass('please_wait_box');
$('#please_wait_box').show();


In your css class

.hidden
{
    display:none;
}


/* use as per your need i have given in general*/

    .please_wait_box
    {
        display:block;
        position:absolute; 
        top:25px;
        left:30px;  
        /*width:100%;*/
        zindex:1000;
        /*opacity:0.5; /* transparency */  
        filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    }

/* use as per your need i have given in general*/

    .messagebox
    {
        display:block;
        position:absolute; 
        top:25px;
        left:30px;  
        /*width:100%;*/
        zindex:1000;
        /*opacity:0.5; /* transparency */  
        filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    }


Hope this helps

Thanks
```